# Значения выбранного значения массива в jsp select form не передается

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, form

Вот entity

```
public class Item {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "number_model")
private String modelNumber;

@Column(name = "name")
private String modelName;

@OneToOne
@JoinTable(name = "item_style",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "style_id")
)
private Style modelStyle;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="item_material",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="material_id", referencedColumnName="id")
)
private List<Material> materialList;
```

И вот

```
public class Material {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
```

В jsp вот такая строка, другие параметры нормально передаются, а в массиве null

```
<form:select items="${material}" multiple="true" path="materialList" itemValue="id" class="form-Control" />
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема может быть?

Comment: а как Вы на jsp кладете список?

Comment: спасибо, решил данное задание уже, помощь не нужна, извиняюсь